# How can I copy a CHAR Variable to WCHAR Variable  in C++

Tags: c++, windows, char, wchar

I want to convert a CHAR file to UNICODE file.
I read a file character by character in CHAR file type and then save this character in a CHAR Variable and then I want to copy this CHAR Variable to a WCHAR Variable and then I Write the the WCHAR Variable in to a UNICODE file.

here is the code :

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<tchar.h>

int _tmain(int argc, LPCTSTR argv[])
{
    HANDLE hInfile, hOutfile;
    CHAR f1; 
    WCHAR f2;   
    DWORD Rd, Wrt; 
    INT i;
    CreateFile(argv[1], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL,NULL);
    CreateFile(argv[2], GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
    while ((ReadFile(hInfile, &f1, sizeof(CHAR), &Rd, NULL) && Rd>0)) 
    {
        **_tccpy(f2, f1);**
        WriteFile(hOutfile, &f2, Rd, &Wrt, NULL);
    }

    CloseHandle(hInfile);
    CloseHandle(hOutfile);

}
```

in bold code is the problem, how can I copy CHAR Variable to a WCHAR Variable.
the _tccpy function and strcpy function cant do this, because the prototype of both of them is char or wachar.

Comment: Why are you reading the value as a `CHAR` in the first place?

Comment: The better option is to define the variables as type `TCHAR`, and then read the value in from the data file in the correct format to begin with. `TCHAR` is `#defined` by `windows.h` to be the correct variant, either ANSI or Unicode, depending on your build settings.

Comment: Thank you it was true, but the created file is not an Unicode file.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always found [these string basics and conversions](http://www.flounder.com/cstring.htm#String%20Basics) very useful when dealing with Unicode in C++.

Comment: More interesting stuff about [Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and the [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM) for files…

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft Specific
Use `wmain` instead of `main` if you want to write portable code that adheres to the Unicode programming model.

```
wmain( int argc, wchar_t *argv[ ], wchar_t *envp[ ] )
```

wmain at ms  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bky3b5dh(VS.80).aspx